# how to set numbering for obtained eigenvectors?

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

I used the code below to get the eigenvectors of the matrices in the shown text files.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import re
import scipy.linalg as la
data=loadtxt('matKSMMF.txt',skiprows=8) #1st matrix
s = len (data)
print(s)
n=6567
kmat = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for x in range (s):
    m=data[x:x+1,:]
    kmat[int (m[0,0])-1][int (m[0,1])-1]=m[0,2]
K=np.array(kmat)
print (K)
data=loadtxt('matMSMMF.txt',skiprows=8) #2nd matrix
s = len (data)
print(s)
n=6567
Mmat = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for x in range (s):
    m=data[x:x+1,:]
    Mmat[int (m[0,0])-1][int (m[0,1])-1]=m[0,2]
M=np.array(Mmat)
print (M)
inv_M = np.linalg.inv(M)
print(inv_M)
L= la.eig(inv_M @ K)
EI=L[1]
print (EI)
np.savetxt('test.doc', EI)
```

I tried to save the eigenvectors into a txt file and doc, as shown in the code, but I could not because of the amount of data (the original matrices sizes are 6567*6567). How can I reduce the volume of obtained data to be able to store them?

I also need to number these eigenvectors in order to do further processing of them (e.g. multiply some of them or store particular ones). How can I find the nth eigenvector?

Comment: How do you "sort" eigenvectors?

Comment: I don't really understand the size problem: if I'm not mistaken, the total size of the vectors shouldn't exceed the size of the matrix, which comes from a text file... Now for the ordering of vectors, I'd order them by eigenvalue.

Comment: ``L[1][:,n]` corresponds to `L[0][n]`